# Web App Deploy in App Service of Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I published one project from visual studio in one of the app service that I existed in my azure account. Now, I want to check that project in the app service on the azure portal. How to verify that if that project exists (web app) in app service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably simply by accessing the website - if your intended project loads in your browser then it must be there.

But you can view the raw files that make-up an Azure App Service by going:

1. `portal.azure.com`
2. Left-hand sidebar > App Services
3. Click on your website
4. Scroll down the App Service "blade"'s left-hand menu to Development Tools > Advanced Tools (icon is a blue swiss-army knife)
5. A link will appear on the right pane that says "Go "
6. This will open Kudu, the web address will be of the form `https://{appServiceName}.scm.azurewebsites.net`
7. In the top navigation bar, choose Debug Console > CMD (or PowerShell, depending on your preference)
8. The filesystem in an Azure Website is virtualised and segregated on the `D:\` volume.
9. Navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. This is the root of your website. Your Web Deploy files will be located under there, varying based on your Web Deploy configuration.

Here are some helpful articles for further reading about Kudu:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/what-is-kudu-with-david-ebbo/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/
- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu

Comment: Thank you. One more question, can we add two or web apps in the same app service? If yes, Is it recommendable?

Comment: @Vicky Yes, under a child path on the website, e.g. `yourwebsite.com/childappname/` - be sure to use root-relative-paths `~/` in your ASP.NET application and you must also define an "Application scope" in the Azure portal that instructs IIS when an application begins.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. I am bit naive with Azure stuff. I went through your above steps and was able to follow it. But above comment seems to be bit more concise. Can you please elaborate on that like where can I find application scope in azure portal? and what is application scope's purpose? Also when you say use root-relative-paths in .net application - Where and what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @Vicky That's a whole other question. It looks like Microsoft has renamed "Application scope" to "Virtual application". See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure